# take mean of variable defined by string in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

---

Seems like this should be easy but I'm stumped. I've gotten the rough hang of programming with `dplyr` 0.7, but struggling with this: How do I program in `dplyr` if the variable I want to program with will be a string?

I am scraping a database, and for a variety of reasons want to summarize a variable that I will know the position of but not the name of (the thing I want is always the first column of the supplied table, but the name of the variable stored in that column will vary depending on the database being scraped). To use `iris` as an example, suppose that I know that the variable that I want is in the first column

```
library(tidyverse)
desired_var <- colnames(iris)[1]
print(desired_var)
"Sepal.Length"
```

I now want to group by `Species`, and take the mean of `desired_var`, i.e. what I want is to perform

```
iris %>% 
group_by(Species) %>% 
summarise(desired_mean = mean(Sepal.Length))
```

But, now I want to take the mean of a column which is defined by a string stored in `desired_var`

I get how to do this with a "bare" `Sepal.Length`

```
desired_var <- quo(Sepal.Length)

iris %>% 
group_by(Species) %>% 
summarise(desired_mean = mean(!!desired_var))
```

But how in the world do I deal with the fact that I have `"Sepal.Length"` not `Sepal.Length` , i.e. that `desired_var <- "Sepal.Length"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) dynamic variable with !!sym** Use `sym` (or `parse_expr`) like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

desired_var <- "Sepal.Length"

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(desired_mean = mean(!!sym(desired_var))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     Species desired_mean
      <fctr>        <dbl>
1     setosa        5.006
2 versicolor        5.936
3  virginica        6.588
```

**2) summarise_at** As @Phil points out in the comments in the particular case of `summarise` this could be done like this without using any rlang facilities:

```
library(dplyr)

desired_var <- "Sepal.Length"

iris %>% 
   group_by(Species) %>% 
   summarise_at(desired_var, funs(mean)) %>%
   ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     Species Sepal.Length
      <fctr>        <dbl>
1     setosa        5.006
2 versicolor        5.936
3  virginica        6.588
```

**3) dynamic variable and name with !!** If you need to set the name dynamically in (1) then try this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

desired_var <- "Sepal.Length"

desired_var_name <- paste("mean", desired_var, sep = "_")

iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(!!desired_var_name := mean(!!sym(desired_var))) %>%
  ungroup
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     Species mean_Sepal.Length
      <fctr>             <dbl>
1     setosa             5.006
2 versicolor             5.936
3  virginica             6.588
```

Comment: Thanks! `!!!parse_expr` does the trick for a variety of other situations that I need this (e.g. grouping by a string as well)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what advantage this has over `summarize_at`. It seems like a more complex way to achieve the same result.

Comment: @Rich Scriven, Be sure you are using the latest version of each package.  This represents recently added functionality.

Comment: @Phil, I have added your suggestion as (2)

Comment: @Rich_Scriven, Either !! or !!! should work.  !!! is used for splicing multiple arguments but here we have just one so !! is sufficient.  I have simplified answer to use just !! although !!! was not wrong and it does work.

Comment: sym is more appropriate than parse_expr. It's currently in rlang but will be re-exported from dplyr in the next version.

Comment: And I think it's slightly better style to do the coercion outside of the dplyr call. Makes it slightly easier to read.

Comment: Have replaced `parse_expr` with `sym` as per @hadley comment.  I had also tried putting the `parse_expr` (now `sym`) both outside and inside the dplyr pipeline and although the `summarise` statement is simpler if it is placed outside the downside is the need to introduce a new variable that is only used once, the associated mental load of looking it up and the associated code bloat so it seems not worth it IMHO.

Answer (score 3):

You're wondering into `tidyeval` which is a rather new feature of the `tidyverse` (see [here](http://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html)) more used to create functions using `tidyverse` functions. For now it is only available with `dplyr` but the plan is to extend it to the other `tidyverse` packages.

For your need though, you don't really need to get into that, when `summarize_at` will do. This function allows you to extend a particular manipulation that you specify across any variables of your choosing:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(one_of("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")), funs(desired_mean = mean))

# A tibble: 3 x 3
     Species Sepal.Length_desired_mean Sepal.Width_desired_mean
      <fctr>                     <dbl>                    <dbl>
1     setosa                     5.006                    3.428
2 versicolor                     5.936                    2.770
3  virginica                     6.588                    2.974
```

You can store the list of variables into a vector, and then use that vector instead:

```
selected_vectors <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width")
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(one_of(selected_vectors)), funs(desired_mean = mean))
```